# How to inject variable into scope with a decorator?

Tags: python, scope, closures, decorator, python-decorators

[Disclaimer: there may be more pythonic ways of doing what I want to do, but I want to know how python's scoping works here]

I'm trying to find a way to make a decorator that does something like injecting a name into the scope of another function (such that the name does not leak outside the decorator's scope). For example, if I have a function that says to print a variable named `var` that has not been defined, I would like to define it within a decorator where it is called. Here is an example that breaks:

```
c = 'Message'

def decorator_factory(value):
    def msg_decorator(f):
        def inner_dec(*args, **kwargs):
            var = value
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return res
        return inner_dec
    return msg_decorator

@decorator_factory(c)
def msg_printer():
    print var

msg_printer()
```

I would like it to print "`Message`", but it gives:

```
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
```

The traceback even points to wher `var` is defined:

```
<ipython-input-25-34b84bee70dc> in inner_dec(*args, **kwargs)
      8         def inner_dec(*args, **kwargs):
      9             var = value
---> 10             res = f(*args, **kwargs)
     11             return res
     12         return inner_dec
```

So I don't understand why it can't find `var`.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can't. Scoped names (closures) are determined at compile time, you cannot add more at runtime.

The best you can hope to achieve is to add *global* names, using the function's *own* global namespace:

```
def decorator_factory(value):
    def msg_decorator(f):
        def inner_dec(*args, **kwargs):
            g = f.__globals__  # use f.func_globals for py < 2.6
            sentinel = object()

            oldvalue = g.get('var', sentinel)
            g['var'] = value

            try:
                res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                if oldvalue is sentinel:
                    del g['var']
                else:
                    g['var'] = oldvalue

            return res
        return inner_dec
    return msg_decorator
```

`f.__globals__` is the global namespace for the wrapped function, so this works even if the decorator lives in a different module. If `var` was defined as a global already, it is replaced with the new value, and after calling the function, the globals are restored.

This works because any name in a function that is not assigned to, and is not found in a surrounding scope, is marked as a global instead.

Demo:

```
>>> c = 'Message'
>>> @decorator_factory(c)
... def msg_printer():
...     print var
... 
>>> msg_printer()
Message
>>> 'var' in globals()
False
```

But instead of decorating, I could just as well have defined `var` in the global scope *directly*.

Note that altering the globals is not thread safe, and any transient calls to other functions in the same module will also still see this same global.

Comment: So if I do `def msg_printer(): print var` and try calling `msg_printer`, I get the same name error, but if I then define `var='Hi'` and call it, it prints it off fine. In this example, is `var` not being defined at runtime, after `msg_printer` has been compiled?

Comment: Because `var` is not defined in the function or in the parent scopes, `var` is marked, at compile time, as a global name instead. But if there was a parent scope, then at compile time, `var` would be marked as a scoped name instead, at which point the decorator trick would not work anymore either.

Comment: Context of globals may be overwritten when you have several concurrent requests. I thought that impossible, but it is - i used this solution for custom user auth(my fail), and after some time see context change if request wasn't process quick. Pay attention, now i'm looking for new solution.

Comment: @ArtyomLisovskij that’s why my answer includes the warning at the end: *Note that altering the globals is not thread safe*

Comment: Martijn: Truly inspired approach which I just used to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68975106/355230) another question. One question I have for you though is whether it's really necessary to save and restore the original value of `f.__globals__` like that? What undesirable side-effects might there be if its value wasn't restored.

Comment: @martineau: because, as I said in my answer, there could be a prior global name that the decorator is now shadowing. It's generally a bad idea to go rummaging in the global namespace of another module with arbitrary variable names, I should probably add more warnings to this answer.

Comment: @martineau: Future maintainers of a codebase using such a decorator will not thank you for leaving the effects of this decorator lying around after it has run; the code here is abusing the global namespace to achieve something that the global namespace wasn't really designed to do. If you are going to do that it is better to minimise the abuse. Imagine having to add a new global variable to a module, that then *keeps changing mysteriously*. Would you know to look at the decorators used on methods in that module?

Comment: OK, got it. Good points and thanks for the clarification. Didn't grasp that `f.__globals__` was being used by everything else in the module — had the idea is was only used to establish the context that the function itself uses when its code executes and wasn't something that was shared.

Comment: @martineau: it is simply a reference to the module globals dictionary: `vars(sys.modules[f.__module__]) is f.__globals__` (*usualy*, some projects replace the `__module__` reference, like SQLalchemy, which uses metaprogramming to aid documentation).

Answer (score 10):

Here's a way of injecting *multiple* variables into a function's scope in a manner somewhat similar to what @Martijn Pieters does in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862336/355230). I'm posting it primarily because it's a more general solution and would *not* need to be applied multiple times to do it — as would be required by his (and many of the other) answers.

It should be noted that a closure  is formed between the decorated function and the `namespace` dictionary, so changing its contents — e.g. `namespace['a'] = 42` — *will* affect subsequent calls to the function.

```
from functools import wraps

def inject_variables(context):
    """ Decorator factory. """

    def variable_injector(func):
        """ Decorator. """
        @wraps(func)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            func_globals = func.__globals__

            # Save copy of any global values that will be replaced.
            saved_values = {key: func_globals[key] for key in context
                                                        if key in func_globals}
            func_globals.update(context)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                func_globals.update(saved_values)  # Restore replaced globals.

            return result

        return decorator

    return variable_injector


if __name__ == '__main__':
    namespace = dict(a=5, b=3)

    @inject_variables(namespace)
    def test():
        print('a:', a)
        print('b:', b)

    test()
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a clean way to do what you want without using global variable. If you want to be stateless and threads safe, you don't really have the choice.

Use the "kwargs" variable:

```
c = 'Message'

def decorator_factory(value):
    def msg_decorator(f):
    def inner_dec(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["var"] = value
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return inner_dec
return msg_decorator

@decorator_factory(c)
def msg_printer(*args, **kwargs):
    print kwargs["var"]

msg_printer()
```

Comment: How is this conceptually different from passing a positional argument?

Comment: It is not so different, but as it is written for positional argument you should know the position of your argument. As it is a decorator, you do not know it.
**kwargs** is the safest way in point of view because you control the name of your argument.

Comment: @M07 - I was about post this very same solution, but I'm one of those people who read before posting! The only downsides to this are the decorated function has to include **kwargs, which really is not that bad and keyword name collision between the decorator and the decorated, but that can be managed.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Python has *lexical scoping*. That means the meaning of an identifier is determined solely based on the scopes that physically surround it when you look at the source code.

Answer (score 4):

Update `__globals__` works for me.

```
def f():
    print(a)


def with_context(**kw):
    def deco(fn):
        g = fn.__globals__
        g.update(kw)
        return fn

    return deco


with_context(a=3)(f)() # 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple demonstration of using a decorator to add a variable into the scope of a function.

```
>>> def add_name(name):
...     def inner(func):
...         # Same as defining name within wrapped
...         # function.
...         func.func_globals['name'] = name
...
...         # Simply returns wrapped function reference.
...         return func
... 
...     return inner
...
>>> @add_name("Bobby")
... def say_hello():
...     print "Hello %s!" % name
...
>>> print say_hello()
Hello Bobby!
>>>
```

Comment: Note that you are manipulating a shared dictionary here. *Other functions in the same module will see this change too*, and altering the dictionary is not thread-safe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is this a problem even if the value modified by the decorator is not modified any more and only read after the decorator has returned?

Comment: @stackoverflowwww: this modifies the module globals, whenever the function is called.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So why do people not always use the approach suggested above and below by Alexander Otavka and M07, that is, letting the decorator call the decorated functions with arguments and thus pass values to the decorated function?

Comment: @stackoverflowwww: most people *do* use such techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Python is lexically scoped, so I'm afraid there is no clean way to do what you want without some potentially nasty side effects.  I recommend just passing var into the function via the decorator.

```
c = 'Message'

def decorator_factory(value):
    def msg_decorator(f):
        def inner_dec(*args, **kwargs):
            res = f(value, *args, **kwargs)
            return res
        inner_dec.__name__ = f.__name__
        inner_dec.__doc__ = f.__doc__
        return inner_dec
    return msg_decorator

@decorator_factory(c)
def msg_printer(var):
    print var

msg_printer()  # prints 'Message'
```

Comment: What is the `msg_decorator.__name__ = f.__name__` and `msg_decorator.__doc__ = f.__doc__` for? Is it necessary?

Comment: @stackoverflowwww Every function in python has a name (unless it was made with lambda), and many have docstrings.  Both are important for generating documentation, so we copy them to the wrapper function.  I made an error in my answer, they should actually be copied over onto `inner_dec`.

Comment: See also `functools.wraps` for doing this sort of thing

Comment: See obvious from the other answers that there **are** "clean" ways of doing it...

Answer (score 2):

I found an interesting post provides a different solution by creating functions on the fly. Basically:

```
def wrapper(func):
    cust_globals = func.__globals__.copy()

    # Update cust_globals to your liking

    # Return a new function
    return types.FunctionType(
        func.__code__, cust_globals, func.__name__, func.__defaults__, func.__closure__
    )
```

See https://hardenedapple.github.io/stories/computers/python_function_override/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in python functions are objects, you can do...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


class DecorClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.a1 = arg1
        self.a2 = arg2

    def __call__(self, function):
        def wrapped(*args):
            print('inside class decorator >>')
            print('class members: {0}, {1}'.format(self.a1, self.a2))
            print('wrapped function: {}'.format(args))
            function(*args, self.a1, self.a2)
        return wrapped


    @DecorClass(1, 2)
    def my_function(f1, f2, *args):
        print('inside decorated function >>')
        print('decorated function arguments: {0}, {1}'.format(f1, f2))
        print('decorator class args: {}'.format(args))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        my_function(3, 4)
```

and the result is:

```
inside class decorator >>
class members: 1, 2
wrapped function: (3, 4)
inside decorated function >>
decorated function arguments: 3, 4
decorator class args: (1, 2)
```

more explanation here http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html

Answer (score 0):

```py
def merge(d1, d2):
    d = d1.copy()
    d.update(d2)
    return d

# A decorator to inject variables
def valueDecorator(*_args, **_kargs):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapper2(*args, **kargs):
            return f(*args, **kargs)
        wrapper2.__name__ = f.__name__
        wrapper2.__doc__ = f.__doc__
        oldVars = getattr(f, 'Vars', [])
        oldNamedVars = getattr(f, 'NamedVars', {})
        wrapper2.Vars = oldVars + list(_args)
        wrapper2.NamedVars = merge(oldNamedVars, _kargs)
        return wrapper2
    return wrapper

@valueDecorator(12, 13, a=2)
@valueDecorator(10, 11, a=1)
def func():
    print(func.Vars)
    print(func.NamedVars)
```

Instead of revising the global scope, changing the annotated function itself is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I have catched problem with solution using globals.

Context of globals may be overwritten when you have several concurrent requests. I thought that impossible, but it is - after some time I have catched change of context(globals) if request wasn't quick. 
Better solution is to pass variable using kwargs:

```
def is_login(old_fuction):
    def new_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        secret_token = request.COOKIES.get('secret_token')
        if secret_token:
            items = SomeModel.objects.get(cookie = secret_token)
            if len(items) > 0:
                item = items[0]
                kwargs['current_user'] = item
                return old_fuction(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('error')
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    return new_function

@is_login  
def some_func(request, current_user):
    return HttpResponse(current_user.name)
```

You'll have to add extra parameter to each decorated function.