# Change the scope of a function in Python

Tags: python, scope, closures

My goal is to change the scope of a function to a dictionary, instead of where it is defined, so that the function sees the variables in the dictionary.

I found out I was able to do the following:

```py
my_dict = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}

def add_all():
  x + y + z

# reference the functions in the dictionary
my_dict.update({'add_all': add_all})

# append my_dict to __global__ of the function
my_dict['add_all'].__globals__.update(my_dict)

z = 3

my_dict['add_all']() # sees x, y and z
# 6
```

This works, now I try to make another function that changes the variables in the enclosing scope.

```py
def update_x_y(x, y):
   # Have to explicitly refer to my_dict here
   my_dict.update({'x': x, 'y': y})
   # Must update the __globals__ of add_all() again
   add_all.__globals__.update(my_dict)
   add_all()

my_dict.update({'update_x_y': update_x_y})
my_dict['update_x_y'].__globals__.update(my_dict)

my_dict['update_x_y'](10, 20)
# 33
```

This also works, but very inelegant and dangerous.

Questions:

- It looks like `__globals__` is a dictionary in which a function will evaluate; What I'm doing with `__globals__.update()` is merely giving it some new values, so each time something changes in `my_dict`, I have to update again.

  - Is there a way that I could supplant `__globals__` with `my_dict`, albeit `readonly`?
- In the `update_x_y()` function, I had to explicitly refer to `my_dict` which is defined in the global scope.

  - Is there a way in functions to refer to variables in the outer scope?
  - `nonlocal` cannot be used, because the enclosing scope has to be a closure

Comment: Can you give more context on you aim? This smells like an XY problem

Comment: hi  @Chris_Rands, I'm just trying to use `my_dict` as the enclosing scope of both functions to evaluate under.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a variable injection class to clean up the code

Inspired by

- [How to inject variable into scope with a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862185/how-to-inject-variable-into-scope-with-a-decorator)
- [Using classes as decorators](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html)

**Code**

```
class Inject_Variables:
    """ Injects Named Variables into function scope """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    
      if kwargs:
        self.kwargs = kwargs
      
    def __call__(self, f):
      """
       __call__() is only called
      once, as part of creation of the wrapped function! You can only give
      it a single argument, which is the function object.
      """
      @wraps(f)
      def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
        f_globals = f.__globals__
        saved_values = f_globals.copy() # shallow copy

        # Add Object creation context
        if self.kwargs:
          f_globals.update(self.kwargs)

        # Add Function call context
        if kwargs:
          f_globals.update(kwargs)

        try:
          result = f()
        finally:
          f_glabals = saved_values # Undo changes

        return result

      return wrapped_f
```

**Use Cases**

```
def add_all():
  return x + y + z
```

Test 1

```
my_dict = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}

z = 3
# Create add that will use my_dict and z in global scope
scoped_add = Inject_Variables(**my_dict)(add_all)
print('Using global z: ', scoped_add())    # use my_dict values
# Output: Using global z:  6
```

Test 2

```
print('Using calling parameter z: ', scoped_add(z=0)) 
# Output: Using calling parameter z:  3
```

Test 3

```
# Update dictionary
my_dict = {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 0}
scoped_add = Inject_Variables(**my_dict)(add_all)  # new scoped add
print('Using dictionary z: ', scoped_add())
# Ouput: Using updated dictionary:  5
```

Test 4

```
# Using name parameters
# Define new scope using named parameters
z = 300
scoped_add = Inject_Variables(x = 100, y = 200)(add_all)
print('Using named parameters: ', scoped_add())
# Output: Using named parameters:  600
```

Test 5

```
z = 3
@Inject_Variables(x=1, y = 2)
def test_all():
    return x + y + z

print('Using in decorator: ', test_all())
# Output: Using in decorator:  6
```

Comment: This looks wonderful. However, I'm wondering if this is setup can let the function manipulate the data in the dictionary as well, or it only flows one-way?

Comment: @SiqiZhang--seems you could manipulate the data in`__init__` and `__call__`.  Depends upon how dynamic you need the manipulations.  Also you can easily just create a different function (i.e. scoped_add) with different data.