# Python Click: access option values globally

Tags: python, python-click

Say I have an flag `--debug/--no-debug` defined for the base command. This flag will affect the behavior of many operations in my program. Right now I find myself passing this flag as function parameters all over the place, which doesn't seem elegant. Especially when I need to access this flag in a deep call stack, I'll have to add this parameter to every single function on the stack.

I can instead create a global variable `is_debug` and set its value at the beginning of the command function that receives the value of this flag. But this doesn't seem elegant to me either.

Is there a better way to make some option values globally accessible using the Click library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do so, depending on your needs. Both of them end up using the click [Context](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Context).

Personally, I'm a fan of **Option 2** because then I don't have to modify function signatures (and I rarely write multi-threaded programs). It also sounds more like what you're looking for.

### Option 1: Pass the Context to the function

Use the `click.pass_context` decorator to pass the click context to the function.

Docs:

- Usage: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts
- API: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.pass_context

```
# test1.py
import click


@click.pass_context
def some_func(ctx, bar):
    foo = ctx.params["foo"]
    print(f"The value of foo is: {foo}")


@click.command()
@click.option("--foo")
@click.option("--bar")
def main(foo, bar):
    some_func(bar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
$ python test1.py --foo 1 --bar "bbb"
The value of foo is: 1
```

### Option 2: `click.get_current_context()`

Pull the context directly from the current thread via `click.get_current_context()`. Available starting in Click 5.0.

Docs:

- Usage: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#global-context-access
- API: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.get_current_context

**Note:** This only works if you're in the current thread (the same thread as what was used to set up the click commands originally).

```
# test2.py
import click


def some_func(bar):
    c = click.get_current_context()
    foo = c.params["foo"]
    print(f"The value of foo is: {foo}")


@click.command()
@click.option("--foo")
@click.option("--bar")
def main(foo, bar):
    some_func(bar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
$ python test2.py --foo 1 --bar "bbb"
The value of foo is: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on top of the *Option 2* given by @dthor, I wanted to make this more seamless, so I combined it with the [trick to modify global scope of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862336/95750) and came up with the below decorator:

```
def with_click_params(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        g = func.__globals__
        sentinel = object()

        ctx = click.get_current_context()
        oldvalues = {}
        for param in ctx.params:
            oldvalues[param] = g.get(param, sentinel)
            g[param] = ctx.params[param]

        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            for param in ctx.params:
                if oldvalues[param] is sentinel:
                    del g[param]
                else:
                    g[param] = oldvalues[param]

    return wrapper
```

You would use it like this (borrowing sample from @dthor's answer):

```
@with_click_params
def some_func():
    print(f"The value of foo is: {foo}")
    print(f"The value of bar is: {bar}")


@click.command()
@click.option("--foo")
@click.option("--bar")
def main(foo, bar):
    some_func()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is it in action:

```
$ python test2.py --foo 1 --bar "bbb"
The value of foo is: 1
The value of bar is: bbb
```

**Caveats**:

- Function can only be called from a `click` originated call stack, but this is a conscious choice (i.e., you would make assumptions on the variable injection). The [click unit testing guide](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/testing/) should be useful here.
- The function is no longer thread safe.

It is also possible to be explicit on the names of the params to inject:

```
def with_click_params(*params):
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            g = func.__globals__
            sentinel = object()

            ctx = click.get_current_context()
            oldvalues = {}
            for param in params:
                oldvalues[param] = g.get(param, sentinel)
                g[param] = ctx.params[param]

            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                for param in params:
                    if oldvalues[param] is sentinel:
                        del g[param]
                    else:
                        g[param] = oldvalue

        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper


@with_click_params("foo")
def some_func():
    print(f"The value of foo is: {foo}")


@click.command()
@click.option("--foo")
@click.option("--bar")
def main(foo, bar):
    some_func()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```