# Way to extend context of function? for example in decorator

Tags: python, decorator

As for example if want let decorated function see logger from closure

```
def logged(func):
    #here i want create logger which i want to be available from decorated function.
    @wraps(func)
    def _logged(*args, **kwargs):
        
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
        #naive idea hot to do it - obviously doesn't work
        #return exec('func(*args,**kwargs)',dict(func=func,logger=logger,args=args,kwargs=kwargs),dict(func=func,logger=logger,args=args,kwargs=kwargs))
    return _logged
```

Comment: Pass the logger to the decorated function as a parameter.  Note that this requires that the decorated function accepts the logger argument (but the caller does not need to pass it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's (another) way to do it, but again it's not through a closure which are determined at compile time, so can't be added at runtime. This version adds a global variable to the function's global namespace, taking care to save and restore the value of any similarly named variable that was already there. I got the idea from @[Martijn Pieters'](https://www.zopatista.com/) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862336/355230) to the somewhat related question: [How to inject variable into scope with a decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862185/how-to-inject-variable-into-scope-with-a-decorator)

```
from functools import wraps


class Logger:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return print(*args, **kwargs)


def logged(func):
    logger = Logger()  # Get or create value to be added.
    varname = 'logger'
    sentinel = object()

    @wraps(func)
    def _logged(*args, **kwargs):
        namespace = func.__globals__
        oldvalue = namespace.get(varname, sentinel)  # Save prev value.
        namespace[varname] = logger

        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            if oldvalue is sentinel:
                del namespace[varname]
            else:
                namespace[varname] = oldvalue

    return _logged


@logged
def myfunc():
    logger('Logged from myfunc.')


myfunc()  # -> Logged from myfunc.
```

Comment: You are the greatest) Great thanks, this does even more then i'm asking for.

Comment: That's great to hear ;¬) and you're welcome. But @Martijn Pieters merits the credit for devising this approach. Thank you for providing motivation for me to discover it.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it a precondition for decorating a function that your function will receive a logger as an argument: it's just not something the *result* will take. (This is similar to how `mock.patch` works as a decorator.)

```
def logged(func):
    logger = ...

    @wraps(func)
    def _logged(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, logger=logger, **kwargs):
    return _logged


@logged
def foo(x, y, *, logger):
    ...

foo(3, 5)
```

Despite appearances, `logger` is *not* a required keyword-only argument, because the name `foo` does not refer to your 3-argument function anymore. It refers to the function that `logged` creates, which will take care of passing the logger to your *original* `foo` when it finally gets called.

If you don't like having `logger` appear to be required, you can give it any default value you like, because that default value will never be used.

```
@logged
def foo(x, y, *, logger=None):
    ...
```

---

Note that while `_logged` is a closure, `func` is *not*, because closures deal with lexical scopes, and `func` was not defined in a lexical scope where `logger` was defined.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to making it seen via a closure would be to make it an attribute of the decorated function. Runnable example:

```
from functools import wraps


class Logger:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return print(*args, **kwargs)


def logged(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _logged(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args,**kwargs)

    _logged.logger = Logger()  # Make attribute of wrapped function.

    return _logged


@logged
def myfunc():
    myfunc.logger('Logged from myfunc')


myfunc()  # -> Logged from myfunc
```