# python hints for decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting

I'm trying to write a framework using decorators and I want the user code to be as clean as possible but also work well with python hints and I have some trouble.

Imagine the next scenario:

framework.py:

```
from dependency import (getSomeThirdPartyPythonClass, SomeClass)

def my_framework_decorator(function):
    def wrapper():
        dependency : SomeClass = getSomeThirdPartyPythonClass()
        function(function)
    return wrapper
```

framework_user.py:

```
from framework import my_framework_decorator

@my_framework_decorator
def user_foo(dependency):
    dependency. # and now I want auto complete of the SomeClass's functions and members
                # from the IDE or from the linter.
```

I don't want to make the users import from "dependency"

Worth mentioning that I'm working with vscode but tried also pycharm and in both, I'm not getting the wanted result.
I played with the setting.json file and the linter attributes but nothing helped.

If you can point for some good linter tool or familiar with a solution to the problem or mention some other elegant approach it will be great.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since `user_foo` is still a standalone function. Decorating it with `my_framework_decorator` means `user_foo = my_framework_decorator(user_foo)`,  but that doesn't mean the only thing that's ever going to be passed into `user_foo` will be `SomeClass` (at least not from the type checker's / linter's perspective). But your users can do `from framework import SomeClass` instead and then type hint manually. If you want this to be more bundled, you can also set `my_framework_decorator.type = SomeClass` and then users would type hint with `my_framework_decorator.type`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862185/how-to-inject-variable-into-scope-with-a-decorator

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, neither pyright (VS Code) or mypy will infer the arguments of a decorated function according to the decorator.

However, you can still type the decorator, and the type checkers will check it against any types the user provides.

So,

**lib.py**

```py
from typing import Callable
from dependency import Dog


def my_decorator(function: Callable[[Dog], None]):
    def wrapper():
        argument: Dog = Dog()
        function(argument)

    return wrapper
```

**app.py**

```py
from lib import my_decorator


@my_decorator
def foo(animal):
    animal.quack()
```

As written, pyright and mypy treat `animal` as Unknown and won't complain here. However, if the user were to type the function arguments, like:

```py
@my_decorator
def foo(animal: Duck):
    animal.quack()
```

Then we'd get an error:

Pyright:
[image: VScode error]

mypy:

```
app.py:7: error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[Duck], Any]"; expected "Callable[[Dog], None]"
```

That would prompt the user to add the correct hint, and then they'd get:

[image: autocomplete]

...proper autocomplete.

---

So there is still an advantage to typing the decorator. And, if users are running a type checker in strict mode, this would be enforced.

Comment: I went on this direction eventually. But I used the decorator to describe a functor instead of just function (hope that's good idea). And I have a type definition to "SomeClass" in the functor scope which used in the signature of the wrapped function.

something like:

class functorFramework:
  classType = SomeClass
  def __init__(self, func : Callable[[classType],None]): self.func = func
  def __call__(self): dependency : classType = getSomeThirdPartyPythonClass() ; self.func(dependency)

@functorFramework
def func(dep : functorFramework.classType): dep. #getting here autocomplete