# How to load a method from a file into an existing class (a 'plugin' method)

Tags: python, plugins

Call me weird if you like, many have before, but I have a large class which I'd like to make extensible with methods loaded from a plugin directory.  Essentially, I'm monkey patching the class.  What I have almost works but the method loaded doesn't 'see' the globals defined in `__main__`.  Ideally I'd like a way to tell globals() (or whatever mechanism is actually used to locate global variables) to use that existing in `__main__`.  Here is the code I have (trimmed for the sake of brevity):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import importlib
import os
import types

main_global = "Hi, I'm in main"

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, plugin_dir=None):

        if plugin_dir:
            self.load_plugins(plugin_dir, ext="plugin")

    def load_plugins(self, plugin_dir, ext):
        """ Load plugins

            Plugins are files in 'plugin_dir' that have the given extension.
            The functions defined within are imported as methods of this class.
        """
        cls = self.__class__

        # First check that we're not importing the same extension twice into
        # the same class.
        try:
            plugins = getattr(cls, "_plugins")
        except AttributeError:
            plugins = set()
            setattr(cls, "_plugins", plugins)

        if ext in plugins:
            return
        plugins.add(ext)

        for file in os.listdir(plugin_dir):
            if not file.endswith(ext):
                continue
            filename = os.path.join(plugin_dir, file)

            loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("bar", filename)
            module = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
            loader.exec_module(module)

            for name in dir(module):
                if name.startswith("__"):
                    continue

                obj = getattr(module, name)
                if callable(obj):
                    obj = obj.__get__(self, cls)
                setattr(cls, name, obj)

z = MyClass(plugin_dir="plugins")
z.foo("Hello")
```

And this is 'foo.plugin' from the plugins directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

foo_global = "I am global within foo"

def foo(self, value):
  print(f"I am foo, called with {self} and {value}")
  print(f"foo_global = {foo_global}")
  print(f"main_global = {main_global}")
```

The output is...

```
I am foo, called with <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fd4680bfac8> and Hello
foo_global = I am global within foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plugged", line 55, in <module>
    z.foo("Hello")
  File "plugins/foo.plugin", line 8, in foo
    print(f"main_global = {main_global}")
NameError: name 'main_global' is not defined
```

I know it all feels a bit 'hacky', but it's become a challenge so please don't flame me on style etc.  If there's another way to achieve this aim, I'm all ears.

Thoughts, learned friends?

Comment: *"If there's another way to achieve this aim, I'm all ears."*: it looks like multiple inheritance would do the job nicely and maybe more intuitively.

Comment: I've just been reading an answer to a similar question, making inheritance a good option except that I want the plugins to be dynamic in that adding a new plugin file will automatically add it to the class next time the code is run.  I don't want to be specifying the plugin files in the main code.  The idea is that the class could be 'adjusted' simply by adding/removing the plugin files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach the problem with a factory function and inheritance. Assuming each of your plugins is something like this, defined in a separate importable file:

```
class MyPlugin:
    foo = 'bar'

    def extra_method(self):
        print(self.foo)
```

You can use a factory like this:

```
def MyClassFactory(plugin_dir):

    def search_and_import_plugins(plugin_dir):
        # Look for all possible plugins and import them
        return plugin_list  # a list of plugin classes, like [MyPlugin]

    plugin_list = search_and_import_plugins(plugin_dir):

    class MyClass(*plugin_list):
         pass

    return MyClass()

z = MyClassFactory('/home/me/plugins')
```

Comment: Nice approach.  It does make the plugin slightly more complicated than the simple 'def' I was thinking of, but simply inheriting from all the plugins is nice.  I can see a possible problem if two plugins choose the same class name but that would also be an issue with duplicate plugin function names.  I'll have a play...

Comment: It's been a long delay but finally tried this out.  I'm back to a 'globals' problem though.  The class in the plugin has no visibility of global vars as its globals() is restricted to the file it's defined in while importing and it doesn't see the globals of the main script.  What I think I need is some mechanism whereby I can say, "import this module, setting its globals to my globals".

Comment: Sorry it's been a long time, but finally accept this as being the 'nicer' of the answers.  I'm using something very similar to the above, scanning the files and loading them in while collecting the names of the classes.  This is done before main main class, which then has all the names given to inherit from.  I also, with a lot of search and replace, fixed the 'globals' problem by defining a 'class G' in a globals.py, then referencing that from all the plugins and the main code.  I'll endeavour to post as an answer to my own question for those interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a variation of the technique shown in @Martijn Pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862336/355230) to the the question: [How to inject variable into scope with a decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862185/how-to-inject-variable-into-scope-with-a-decorator) tweaked to inject *multiple* values into a class method.

```
from functools import wraps
import importlib
import os
from pathlib import Path
import types


main_global = "Hi, I'm in main"

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, plugin_dir=None):
        if plugin_dir:
            self.load_plugins(plugin_dir, ext="plugin")

    def load_plugins(self, plugin_dir, ext):
        """ Load plugins

            Plugins are files in 'plugin_dir' that have the given extension.
            The functions defined within are imported as methods of this class.
        """
        cls = self.__class__

        # First check that we're not importing the same extension twice into
        # the same class.
        try:
            plugins = getattr(cls, "_plugins")
        except AttributeError:
            plugins = set()
            setattr(cls, "_plugins", plugins)

        if ext in plugins:
            return
        plugins.add(ext)

        for file in Path(plugin_dir).glob(f'*.{ext}'):
            loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("bar", str(file))
            module = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
            loader.exec_module(module)
            namespace = globals()

            for name in dir(module):
                if name.startswith("__"):
                    continue

                obj = getattr(module, name)
                if callable(obj):
                    obj = inject(obj.__get__(self, cls), namespace)

                setattr(cls, name, obj)


def inject(method, namespace):

    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        method_globals = method.__globals__

        # Save copies of any of method's global values replaced by the namespace.
        replaced = {key: method_globals[key] for key in namespace if key in method_globals}
        method_globals.update(namespace)

        try:
            method(*args[1:], **kwargs)
        finally:
            method_globals.update(replaced)  # Restore any replaced globals.

    return wrapped


z = MyClass(plugin_dir="plugins")
z.foo("Hello")
```

Example output:

```
I am foo, called with <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0056F670> and Hello
foo_global = I am global within foo
main_global = Hi, I'm in main
```

Comment: An excellent improvement!  However, if I declare 'global main_global' within foo, assigning to it doesn't affect the 'real' main_global as it does in a method defined directly in the class.