# use raw_input generated string safely (Python)

Tags: python, user-input, raw-input

I'm wondering how to use a string from raw_input safely so that I can create a function to replace it for a script that is meant to be used easily and securely.

The reason is that I am trying to make a character sheet generating application using python and need to be able to get a character's full name to pass as a string using a name for easy access (Charname_NLB)

However, as I'm looking to use this for more than that application, I need this to be usable for any string entered as raw input, using this alternate command.

I already have a similar piece made for input of integers and would like to integrate it into the same class, for simplicity's sake. I'll post it here, with thanks to: Mgilson and BlueKitties (from here and www.python-forum.org respectively)

```
    def safeinput(get_num):
            num = float(raw_input(get_num))
            return num
```

However if this would not return the same result as the base Input command safely, could I please get an working copy, as I currently have only one proof of concept to work with, and it wouldn't be accurate with truncated numbers.

**Edit: By "Any string", I mean specifically that the result will be stored as a string, not used as a command.

Comment: good day. what is your question?

Comment: When you say "any string"- are you including executable Python code? Or only literals like ints, floats, lists, strings...

Comment: if you want enter executable python code you may use 'input()' instead 'raw_input()'

Comment: Zagorulkin: But that wouldn't be safe. I think the idea is to use `eval` on the input string, but prevent any malicious behavior. (Like I said, this would be possible if he just wants literals to be input, but if he actually wants to be able to provide Python code...)

Comment: delete sys.path and execute in a sandbox? (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558104/python-evalcompile-sandbox-globals-go-in-sandbox-unless-in-def-why)

Comment: Okay, this question may have been pointless if raw_input() is safe by default. If it is, I certainly have been wasting my time.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for. `literal_eval` is safe, but only works for literals. It's very difficult to use `eval()` safely if you have to sanitise the input

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> def safeinput(s):
...     try:
...         return literal_eval(s)
...     except:
...         return s
... 
>>> repr(safeinput("1"))
'1'                                            # converted to an int
>>> repr(safeinput("1.1"))
'1.1'                                          # converted to a float
>>> repr(safeinput("'some string in quotes'"))
"'some string in quotes'"                      # converted to a string
>>> repr(safeinput("some string without quotes"))
"'some string without quotes'"                 # no conversion necessary
```