# How to call a compiled function body?

Tags: python, unit-testing, introspection

When I get hold of a code object (via internals like `.func_code` or `__code__` in Python 3), is there any way of *calling* this piece of code?  Simply calling it does not work:

```
def f(): pass

f.func_code()
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'code' object is not callable
```

This can come in handy when you like to unit-test a nested function:

```
def f():
  def g():
    return 3
  f.x = g
  return g() + 1

f.func_code.co_consts[1]
```

results in

```
<code object g at 0x7f123991b930, file "<stdin>", line 2>
```

Of course, this piece of code still needs a context etc. but that's not my question here.

Comment: You can `eval` or `exec` them.

Comment: You could create a new function and assign `func_code` to it. See the `add_self()` function in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3454053/355230) that shows doing something like that.

Comment: @vaultah That's exactly the solution for me!  Do you care to put that in an A, so I can accept it, just to close this Q properly?

Comment: No, but you can post it yourself. :)

Comment: @vaultah My code objects have "free variables" and I always get an error message when giving them to `eval()`.  Any idea how to call these?

Comment: @vaultah And how can I give parameters to the code object when evaluating it using `eval()`?

Comment: @Alfe you may get the `function` type (`types.FunctionType`) and use it to construct a new function object. For the description of parameters see `types.FunctionType.__doc__`.

Answer (score 2):

One can `eval()` or `exec` them.

If they have *free variables* (e. g. for the code of nested functions whose outer function has local variables defined before the nested function), this is not directly possible (`eval` or `exec` raise a `TypeError` in this case).

Also, passing arguments to the code is not directly possible.

But one can create a wrapping function for the given code on-the-fly.  This function can normally be called (using `f(…)`), passing arguments in the usual way.  This is done using `types.FunctionType`.  To achieve references to *free variables*, one must use a trick in order to get the correct data type as Python expects it.  See the code below for an example:

```
def f(v1=1):
  v2 = 2
  def g(v3=4):
    return v1 + v2 + v3 + 8
  return g() + 16

def freeVar(val):
  def nested():
    return val
  return nested.__closure__[0]

def nested(outer, innerName, **freeVars):
  if isinstance(outer, (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
    outer = outer.func_code
  for const in outer.co_consts:
    if isinstance(const, types.CodeType) and const.co_name == innerName:
      return types.FunctionType(const, globals(), None, None, tuple(
          freeVar(freeVars[name]) for name in const.co_freevars))

nestedG = nested(f, 'g', v1=1, v2=2)
print nestedG(4)  # will print 15
```