# Is there a way to call a function inside a function

Tags: python

Is there a way I could access a function that is nested inside another function. For example, I have this block of code right here. For example, I did `f().s()` but it did not work:

```
def f():   
 def s():   
     print(13)
```

Comment: `f().s()` means the result of `f()` is an object on which you are calling `s()`
Which doesn't seems so in your case

Comment: Short answer: no. You can do something similar with classes though.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: if you want nested function to be called in outer scope better define it outside

Comment: The code object is at `f.__code__.co_consts[1]` but turning that into a callable function has a few hoops to jump through. How this is done in unit tests is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505380/how-to-call-code-objects-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```py
def f():
    def s():
        print(13)
    return s
```

Then you can call:

```py
>>> f()()
13
```

Or if you want to have f().s():

```py
def f():
   class S:
        def s():
            print(13)
    return S
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the second function is a global var, then you'd need to call the first function in order for Python interpreter to create that second function.

See below;

```
>>> def foo():
...     global bar
...     def bar():
...             print("Hello world!")
... 
>>> bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>> foo()
>>> bar()
Hello world!
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you certainly could do something

```
def f():
   def s():
      print("S")
   return s

f()()
```

you could also expose them in an internal dict

```
def f(cmd):
    return {"s": lambda: do_something_s,"y": lambda: do_something_y}.get(cmd,lambda:invalid_cmd)()
```

then use `f("s")` or `f("y")`

none of these are likely to be the correct solution to what you are actually trying to achieve ...